# Do i need a website for my android project?

Tags: java, android, webserver

Do i need a website for my mobile application to manage admin page or i could do this within the app?

Comment: You don't have to have a website, but the easiest way to get data from a remote server is through HTTP.  Your server doesn't have to have an actual visual website per se, but you'll need hosting and I think the monetary cost is what you are trying to avoid, which you won't be able to.

Comment: Thank you sir! I will look forward to that. You really nailed it, what i'm really avoiding is the monetary cost.

Comment: There isn't much you can do about the money, unless you want to host the server yourself.  Not really recommended because that can open a whole new set of problems.

Comment: Am not looking forward to host the server at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make your app get videos and pictures from a file hosting service like google drive but still you need a server to store links to those videos this way you reduce Hosting expenses.

Comment: thank you, sir! I will check out google drive API too.

Comment: You dont need the api, you can just upload files to your drive and use the link for the image/video in you app. as said if you want to change/add content you will need to store the links somewhere, insted of using server you can upload a file with json/xml format to your drive and save the link there and read the links form the file(or multiple files if it would make it easier on you), if you decide you actually need server check my answer I posted, worked like a charm for me and 100% free of charge.

Comment: But i want my user to be able to view the video. How do achieve that?

Answer (score -3):

If your concern for owning a website is just payment you can just try free storage/server/domain websites like webhost or  [hostinger](http://www.hostinger.com/)

As mentioned it's free as long as you dont buy "extra" services (which isn't necessary since they offer a lot to begin with! at least it is the case for me, you get somthing like -  2GB storage, 100,000 Mega bandwidth, 2 MYSQL databases and i think 2 free domains for a website (you dont have to build a website you can just use the storage like I do)

you can also try:

1.uploading videos to youtube

2.google drive maybe

3.free image storage website (make sure it wont get deleted after some time like in some of the websites).